# Android - animate View object - specific XML <set>

Tags: android, xml, animation

I'm new to Android application programming, and using search i've so far solved all of my problems (stackoverflow being one of the best search hits !)

Now i have a problem i don't know how to solve :

When separate animations are required, i could do it in code, but using XML files in anim folder would be much better for me.

Is it possible to play an animation of a single `<set>` inside XML file ?
I mean is it possible to "compress" animations from mulitple XML files into one file and still use them individually ?

Example for normal animation of TextView widget :

```
TexView exampleTextView = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.example_textview);
Animation animatorSequence = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation (this, R.anim.example_animation);
exampleTextView.startAnimation (animatorSequence);
```

XML code with two example  blocks that i would like to use separately

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--first independant animation segment -->
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:duration="1400" />
</set>
<!--second independant animation segment -->
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:duration="1400" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

But you can divide them to multiple files, load the in run time and add them all to a single `AnimationSet` (You can also define the empty set itself in a XML file so you won't have to configure it programmatically).

Comment: Thanks. I've read the google docs and will try it out. At a glance, `AnimationSet` does allow chaining, but it lacks removal method. I could rebuild the entire chain excluding the unwanted animation set, but that is just cumbersome. Waaait ! If i can define empty set and fill it in later in code, can i also erase it ? Make it empty again so it's harmlessly bypassed ?

Comment: I would not worry about removing animation from the set, it's a pretty much light object so you won't have any trouble with memory if you create multiple instances.
If I were to implement it, I would create a static helper class the creates my custom animations. For example: `AnimationUtils.getWelcomeScreenAnimation` that inflates the `AnimationSet` and add all the relevant animations.